# I really need help organizing my websites files

Tags: code-organization, project-organization, file-organization

Okay I am having trouble organizing all my files for my website. I can't really find an efficient way to organize the files at all.

This is how I currently organize my files..
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKu0o.jpg

Is this a good way to organize them? Or is there a better and cleaner way because I feel like this will start to get annoying in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would aim to have all of the files for each site (learningjs and msw) stored in their own folder.

so in /sites/learningjs for example I'd create a /css, /js and /img folder and move in the various learningjs files in there.  That means if you want to download/open source your project in the future, then all the files will be in the right place.

You might end up with multiple copies of jquery - but actually that's okay, because you might want to use a newer copy of jquery in one project, but the old version in a different project.

Have a look at http://www.initializr.com/ and see how it builds a project for you.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking of doing because I like having the website like "http://website.com/learningjs" instead of "http://website.com/sites/learningjs." Okay well thank you, I just wanted other peoples opinions, so I will probably do that.

**PS**

So I shouldn't have a folder just called js or css? I should just have all the required files inside that one folder?

Comment: that seems like a sensible way to allow you keep adding more sites without loads of clutter.

Comment: Alright well thank you very much

Comment: Also I don't think I will be using the initialzr. It's a good idea but I like building from scratch and learning myself instead of having a template. Maybe when I am a pro and get tired of creating them myself I will.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan to me :)  You say below that later you're going to learn PHP.  Instead, I'd recommend checking out www.railsforzombies.org .  Not particularly because I think you should use Ruby on Rails for your projects, but if you can understand the ideas contained in this course, you'll be better than 95% of people who call themselves "web developers".  Good luck!